# C#: How to access function in EXE from CLR code built as dll?

Tags: c#

I have created CLR in C# that handles triggers from SQL database. This is built as a dll. There is another file that is built as exe and creates a singleton instance of a TCPServer. I want to access the TCPServer instance in the dll to send the data that is received in the trigger. How can I do this? When I try using the namespace in the file, it is giving me error. Is there a way I can access the instance and its functions from the file that is built as an exe from a file that is built as a dll? Or is this a very bad design? Basic idea is to handle the SQL trigger and post the data to a socket. I am fairly new to both c# and SQL.

Code for CLR:

```
    namespace trigger
    {
       public class X
       {
           public static void trig_hdl()
           {
           }
       }
    }
```

This is built as dll: csc /t:library

Code for TCPServer:

```
namespace TCP
{
   public class TCPServer
   {
     public void sendTo()
   }
}
```

This is built as exe.

Now from trig_hdl() how do I access sendTo()?

Comment: Hard to follow. Try posting some (schematic) code. Name things.

Comment: And I doubt that you built a 'CLR'.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference whether the assembly is an 'exe' or 'dll' (if it is a .Net assembly), first of all you should reference it, then you will have the ability to use the code located in assembly, if both projects are in the same solution then there is absolutely no problem, just reference your project.

Regarding bad design, it seems that it really is bad, the basic idea is that you use shared class library where you put all shared code. After that you just reference that library from both of your projects, and use the code located there...

Comment: Yes, referencing a .exe project or assembly in a class library project is totally back to front and makes no sense.